# awk or bash for split lines

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to split a csv file which looks like this:

```
a|b|1,2,3
c|d|4,5
e|f|6,7,8
```

the goal is this format:

```
a|b|1
a|b|2
a|b|3
c|d|4
c|d|5
e|f|6
e|f|7
e|f|8
```

How can I do this in bash or awk?

Comment: this has been asked many times -what did you try?

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
while IFS="|" read -r a b c; do for n in ${c//,/ }; do echo "$a|$b|$n"; done; done <file
```

Output:

```
a|b|1
a|b|2
a|b|3
c|d|4
c|d|5
e|f|6
e|f|7
e|f|8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat hm.awk
{
    s = $0; p = ""
    while (i = index(s, "|")) { # `p':  up to the last '|'
                                # `s':  the rest
      p = p substr(s, 1    ,  i)
      s =   substr(s, i + 1)
    }
    n = split(s, a, ",")
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      print p a[i]
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f hm.awk file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

In Gnu awk (`split`):

```
$ awk '{n=split($0,a,"[|,]");for(i=3;i<=n;i++) print a[1] "|" a[2] "|" a[i]}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

with `perl`

```
$ cat ip.csv 
a|b|1,2,3
c|d|4,5
e|f|6,7,8

$ perl -F'\|' -lane 'print join "|", @F[0..1],$_ foreach split /,/,$F[2]' ip.csv
a|b|1
a|b|2
a|b|3
c|d|4
c|d|5
e|f|6
e|f|7
e|f|8
```

- splits input line on `|` into `@F` array
- then for every comma separated value in 3rd column, print in desired format

For a generic last column,

```
perl -F'\|' -lane 'print join "|", @F[0..$#F-1],$_ foreach split /,/,$F[-1]' ip.csv
```